# how i solve this error in laravel livewire?

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-10

i have some input fileds that are  startdate,enddate,companyname. when i press search button i have to display some details that relevent to  above input fields. when i am insert valid input (avilable data) it is successfully working . when i enter data that dismatch input (entered  data not in the database) then its redirect to error page  i have to avoid that error and show an error message how colud i do that?  i attched the error screen also [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wSY9.png)

i have to fix this

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to post the component livewire code search function and the componente view blade code to help find possible causes of this.